# Unable to render tree like structure in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, treeview, angular5

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 5. I am trying to display tree like structure. I am following the

> https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/blob/master/example/cli/src/app/async/async.component.ts and 
>   https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/async-data-1

In the above example they have given some data and my application works with it. In real time I am using some other data and converting it to exactly the format in the example they have given.

Below is my example.

```
 let results =  JSON.parse('{"userid":"e75792f8-cfea-460e-aca2-07a778c92a7c","tenantid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","username":"karthik","emailaddress":"john@krsars.onmicrosoft.com","isallowed":false,"userroles":[{"userroleid":"b81e63d1-09da-4aa0-af69-0f086ddb20b4","userid":"e75792f8-cfea-460e-aca2-07a778c92a7c","roleid":"85d2f668-f523-4b64-b177-b1a78db74234","tenantappid":1,"validfrom":"2018-01-24T00:00:00","validto":"2018-01-24T00:00:00","isactive":true}]}');
    for (const key in results) {
      if (results[key] instanceof Array) {
        const containerTyp2 = {name: '', hasChildren: false,};

        containerTyp2.name = key;
        containerTyp2.hasChildren = true;

        this.nodes.push(containerTyp2);
     } else {
        const object = {name: ''};
        const containerTyp1 = {name: '', children: []};
        object.name = results[key];
        containerTyp1.name = key;
        containerTyp1.children.push(object);
        this.nodes.push(containerTyp1);
    }
  }
  console.log(this.nodes);
```

Below is the sample data from application example.

```
  this.nodes = [
      {
        name: 'root1',
        children: [
          { name: 'child1' }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'root2',
        hasChildren: true
      },
      {
        name: 'root3'
      }
    ];
```

I am converting my raw data to same format to the example above. When I display both data in console both looks similar except id field. Whenever i display example data, I can see id field get added with random value but explicitly they are not adding. Below is the console of example data.

[image]

Below is the console of raw data.

[image]

Can someone help me to figure out the issue? I am not able to identify what is the reason not to display raw data. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you displaying this data and what is displayed? Any errors in console?

Comment: I am displaying this data in html page. I am displaying data in same place where sample data is displaying. There are no errors. Nothing is displaying. When i do for loop id field is visible in last array but it is not there in previous array

Comment: Show the code where you are actually displaying the data. I get the expected result from your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-esh2hc

Comment: And if you click 'Log data' button, you can see that the id's are added.
Another question is why you actually want to use tree view for data that is not really a tree structure.

Comment: Hi John. I have seen the stackblitz you created. Seems very interesting to me.

Comment: I fixed issue only after adding  this.tree.treeModel.update(); May i know the real issue now?

Comment: You have to provide more code. As you can see from the demo I created, data is not the problem, it's somewhere else. Seems like you may be providing empty array to the component first and for some reason it is not updated when populating it with data.

Comment: Anyway thank you for creating stackblitz. Please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding below line at the end of for loop.

```
 let results=data;
    for (const key in results) {
      if (results[key] instanceof Array) {
        const containerTyp2 = {name: '', hasChildren: false,};

        containerTyp2.name = key;
        containerTyp2.hasChildren = true;

        this.nodes.push(containerTyp2);
     } else {
        const object = {name: ''};

        const containerTyp1 = {name: '', children: []};
        object.name = results[key];
        containerTyp1.name = key;
        containerTyp1.children.push(object);
        this.nodes.push(containerTyp1);
    }
    this.tree.treeModel.update();
```